# Python- How to Remove Columns from a File

Tags: python, file

I'd like to remove the first column from a file. The file contains 3 columns separated by space and the columns has the following titles:
X', 'Displacement' and 'Force' (Please see the image).

[image: data file]

I have came up with the following code, but to my disappointment it doesn't work!

```
f = open("datafile.txt", 'w')
 for line in f:
  line = line.split()
  del x[0]
f.close()
```

Any help is much appreciated !
Esan

Comment: Did you actually read the errors that code threw? I mean, you are using ``'w'`` when reading, a lot of it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you're attempting to read from a file (by iterating through the file contents) that is open for writing. This will give you an `IOError`.

Second, there is no variable named `x` in existence (you have not declared/set one in the script). This will generate a `NameError`.

Thirdly and finally, once you have finished (correctly) reading and editing the columns in your file, you will need to write the data back into the file.

To avoid loading a (potentially large) file into memory all at once, it is probably a good idea to read from one file (line by line) and write to a new file simultaneously.

Something like this might work:

```
f = open("datafile.txt", "r")
g = open("datafile_fixed.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        g.write("\t".join(line.split()[1:]) + "\n")

f.close()
g.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ''.join([' '.join(l.split()[1:]) for l in file('datafile.txt')])
```

or, if you want to preserve spaces and you know that the second column always starts at the, say, 10th character:

```
print ''.join([l[11:] for l in file('datafile.txt')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Some reading about [python i/o](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) might be helpful, but something like the following should get you on your feet:

```
with open("datafile.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("outputfile.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.split(' ')
            if len(line) == 3:
                del line[0]
                fout.write(line[0] + ' ' + line[1])
            else:
                fout.write('\n')
```

EDIT: fixed to work with blank lines